# Unity remote with Google Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

To develop Android apps with Unity the Unity Remote app comes in very handy. It let's you click the play button in Unity and instantly run the app on the device. Furthermore you get live feedback, because you can see all the game objects. This is very helpful for debugging. Unfortunately it does not work out of the box with the Tango device. Maybe there is a workaround for this?

Comment: This is an Android Device. What Unity Remote feature does not work with Tango? What have you tried?

Comment: The regular Unity Remote feature still works on Tango, i.e break point debugging. Which part doesn't work?

Comment: Well the whole pose data and depth info is not available anymore. I would like to inspect the Game Objects that are created on the fly by the mesh example. Maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: Tango data is not available for remote debugging, and probably will never be.. In order to do that, there needs to be another socket open for receiving Tango data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is very frustrating – you end up pushing builds constantly and making debugging UIs just to figure out what is what at runtime. But it looks like, per Jason Guo, that the Tango data is not going to be available to the Unity Remote app. Perhaps if there is enough developer demand in the future there can be a Tango-specific version of the Remote app but for now, build...build...build...

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, did anyone found a solution to this?